# ¿Como importar modulos de scripts con extencion .pyw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyqt5, debian-9

recientemente intento ejecutar en linux (debian 9) una app que estoy programando en windows con python3 y PyQt5

El problema, no puedo importar modulos de ningun script con extencion .pyw

Me explico mejor.

Tengo los archivos en la siguiente carpeta

```
~/Documentos/Codigo/codigo
```

Los archivos son

```
__pycache__

ModuloPy.py

ModuloPyw.pyw

ModuloPyw.ui
```

al ejecutar el script *moduloPy.py*

```
~/Documentos/Codigo/codigo$ python3 moduloPy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moduloPy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moduloPyw import *
ImportError: No module named 'moduloPyw'
```

Las tres primeras lineas de *moduloPy.py* son las siguientes

```
#Principal
import sys
from moduloPyw import *
```

Aclaro que instale correctamente PyQt5 y no tuve errores (al menos es creo)

```
~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>>
```

La verdad no encontre nada parecido en internet.

Gracias.

Comment: La extension pyw está pensada y solo tiene sentido en Windows (para lanzar python.exe (CLI) o pythonw.exe (GUI)). Te recomiendo no nombrar módulos con esta extensión que no sean usados exclusivamente para lanzar la GUI en Windows. Hay formas de importar cualquier fichero sin importar extensión vía importlib por ejemplo, pero no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Listo, cambie la extencion y ahora si lo ejecuta perfectamente. Se agradece.